# Javascript beginner having problems with simple pop ups

Tags: javascript, popup

I am a complete JS newbie and have two pop windows I want open when two buttons are clicked - ask question button opens up a pop up called pop up, and the other button called edit question opens up a pop up called popupEdit. The first in working fine - but the second isn't working at all. I suspect this is a very simple thing...I have just started learning JS to add some style to my PHP only sites. Thanks for the help.

```
 window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("AskQuestion").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    popup.style.display = "block";
  };

   document.getElementById("CloseBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popup.style.display = "none";      
   };

    document.getElementById("EditQuestion").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popupEdit = document.getElementById("popupEdit");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    popupEdit.style.display = "block";
  };

    document.getElementById("CloseEditBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popupEdit = document.getElementById("popup");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popupEdit.style.display = "none";      
  };


 };
```

Comment: The associated HTML should be included in your question.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any typos in the elements' IDs. Other than that, your code looks fine. To be able to actually help you, you'd have to provide a better explanation of what "doesn't work at all" and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a minor mistake with the second popup. There should be `popupEdit` instead of just `popup`:

```
document.getElementById("CloseEditBtn").onclick = function(){
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var popupEdit = document.getElementById("popupEdit");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    popupEdit.style.display = "none";      
};
```

Also make sure you define CSS styles properly.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nRfC2/

Comment: Cheers pal. It works....my problem was also with the CSS. To all the others who commented....thanks. I should have posted more. I apologise for this indiscretion.